# Command Line Acrobat Reader - shifted characters!

Tags: c#, character-encoding, acrobat

In a .NET project we use **Acrobat Reader with the command line option** "/t" which allows to directly print a pdf to the desired printer. To start the printing we use a Process object with corresponding StartInfo.arguments and it is launched like this:

```
Process p = new Process();
[...]
p.Start();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(printerTimeout);
if (!p.HasExited)
{
  p.Kill();             
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

It happens that more than one pdf file must be printed in the same loop.

When only one pdf is printed, no problem. But for a specific installation and when more than one pdf files must be printed, **some pages have shifted characters** (in fact, all characters printed are **shifted to one ASCII code**, i.e. A becomes B, B becomes C etc.). But the originals pdf are correct and don't contain any shifted characters.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: `But for a specific installation...` Uh-Oh, that's a problem. We'd need to know the setup of the machine, and steps you've taken so far to diagnose and fix the problem. The good news, [you're at least not alone](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3408059), [and there seems to be](http://darrenmccall.com/blog/2010/03/19/my-adobe-acrobat-pdf-files-are-printing-garbage-text-sometimes/) [a possible fix by simply printing as image](http://routingbyrumor.wordpress.com/2007/12/30/my-adobe-acrobat-pdf-files-are-printing-garbage-text-sometimes/). Contacting Adobe because of that bug might be an option.

Comment: And now that we nailed the problem, this belongs on SU.